# Giving colors to buildings in CityEngine?

Tags: cityengine

I am new to CityEngine and using trial version 2011.2.I want to know how the colors are given to buildings?

[image]

Cga rule file for buildings I have written is :-

```
*/

version "2011.2"

attr BUILD_HEIGHT=0

attr Mass_Color = "#ffaa33"

attr opacityvalue=0.6

@StartRule

Lot-->

   extrude(BUILD_HEIGHT)

   color(Mass_Color)

   set(material.opacity,opacityvalue)
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or missing ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to change `color(Mass_Color)`

For instance, `color(“#F00100″)` for red.

[CityEngine Tutorial Series: Attributes, Rules, and Base Color](https://gaminggis.wordpress.com/2015/09/13/cityengine-tutorial-series-attributes-rules-and-base-color/)  has a useful guide.

Comment: I tried this too but still it doesn't works.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test your cga in 2011.2 but with 2014.1 your code works as expected (colors the buildings).

You could try to use the other usage way of [color](http://cehelp.esri.com/help/topic/com.procedural.cityengine.help/html/cgareference/op_color.html?resultof=%22%63%6F%6C%6F%72%22%20), i.e. `color(255, 170, 51)`.